# UIDocumentInteractionController - Error while reading the document

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I preview docs in my app using a UIDocumentInteractionController. However, sometimes documents show fine, other times the interactioncontroller displays a message "Error while reading the document". I know it is not an issue with the document, because the same document sometimes shows and sometimes doesn't.

Restarting the device solves this problem temporarily - so it would appear to be a memory issue, but strangely I am not getting any memory warnings. Any ideas on how to get this to work reliably please?

Notes:

1. The documentinteractioncontroller preview is dismissed and the
   controller released when finished to ensure prior previews do not
   remain in memory
2. I had the same issue using the quicklook controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much testing it appears this issue is limited to iPad 1. The only workaround is a restart.

Answer (score 0):

Since you believe that the document in question is correct, and you believe your code is correct, you have to start looking for other factors. Two that come to mind are:

- The state of the application. Is there something about the current state of the app that could be preventing the preview from working? You mentioned that you don't get any memory warnings, but have you looked at how much memory the app is using when the preview succeeds and when it fails?
- The state of the document. Is it possible that the file can't be opened for some reason, such as the file already being open? Can you open the file by any other means?

Comment: I have not examined how much memory that app is using when it fails because I assume that should too much memory be used, I'll get a memory warning. Even if memory usage is high, there is nothing I can do to improve it has the app dismisses all views, except the rootvc, before presenting the interactioncontroller preview. (I have checked for leaks already). As to the second suggestion, I do not believe it has anything to do with the state of the document - the reason is that documents are previewed when "Open in MyApp" is selected in another app which would cause iOS to write it to sandbox dir

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your app is trying to display the doc before the os has finished writing it to the sandbox dir.  The speed of this operation will be somewhat dependent on what else is going on the the background (other apps, email downloading, iOS checking for updates, etc.).  This would also explain why restarting the device can seem to fix the problem temporarily.

To check this, you could check for this error and then try again to open the doc after a few seconds.

Without specific code or or logs, it's tough to say much more.