# UIDocumentInteractionController only shows file name and size when previewing

Tags: ios, uidocumentinteraction

I have a very weird situation. My app tries to preview a pdf file using UIDocumentInteractionController and it sometimes works and other ones don't. I can not see any difference when it works and when it doesn't.

Some clues:

- The file is big (> 45 MB). With smaller files it works
- The file exists and the url is correct (checked before trying to preview it)
- Some memory warnings appear. But they also appear sometimes than UIDocumentInteractionController is able to open the file. So I don't think it's related
- I'm testing on devices (iPad running iOS 8, but base sdks of app is iOS 7), not in simulator
- The only warning I see always that it doesn't work and I don't see when it works is the following:

> : Received unkown error: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain error 3.)" UserInfo=0x14583dd0 {Message=Service Connection Interrupted}

In order to narrow the problem I've done an app that the only thing that it does is to preview a file. After testing I've discovered:

- On iOS 7 it always works perfectly
- On iOS 8 sometimes it works, but if you try with bigger files (>100 MB) it doesn't work

It seems an iOS 8 bug, but if any of you have any idea it would be really appreciated.

Comment: Your issue seems a bit similar to this one.Look at this link, it may helpful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735246/uidocumentinteractioncontroller-error-while-reading-the-document

Comment: After requesting a Technical Support Incident the guys from Apple have told me to open a bug about it. I've also opened the bug. Let's see what happens...